# How to model a simple semi-organic form like this effectively?

Tags: modeling

I tried to recreate a simple ribcage model from these reference images:

[image]

[image]

I ended up achieving something similar with crease edges and subdiv modifier:

[image]

But it was basically modeling by trials and errors. I just manually move vertices after vertices until they somehow resembled the reference. It took me ages and I think if I do it again it won't be much faster.

How could I approach this kind of task effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could begin this way:

[image]